# Django New lines in view variable

Tags: python, django

I am sending email with Django using Sendgrid. I have a variable `message` for the message that will send, however the `message` holds the value of a few other variables. I would like them to be on different lines to make the email easier to read. Here is what I have, although it is not working.

```
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
    phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
    email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    party_size = form.cleaned_data.get('party_size')
    form_message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
    listing_address = listing.address
    message = name + "\n" + phone + "<br>" + email + "<br>" + party_size + "<br>" + listing_address

    send_mail('New Lead', message, 'to email', ['email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

The email is being sent as this:

```
garrett 1234234<br>g@d.com<br>2<br>address would be here
```

Although I would like this:

```
garrett
1234234
g@d.com
2
address would be here
```

Comment: are you used python3 and what veersion of sendgrid?

Comment: @laur Python 3.6, not sure what version of Sendgrid. How do I find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create email template & provide context to email template then use generate email content. Use this content(generated_html) in `send_email`
as parameter `html_message`

```
    send_mail('New Lead', message, 'to email',
        ['email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False, html_message=genenrated_html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send HTML version of email with  [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

message = name + "<br>" + phone + "<br>" + email + "<br>" + party_size + "<br>" + listing_address
msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email, ['email@gmail.com'])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the django snippet that you have given here

In Sendgrid there is a setting to do this

In the [settings](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/mail.html#-Plain-Content) page where you need to make the status as `on`. All your plain text will be converted / parsed to HTML view

Answer (score 0):

trata utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
    phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
    email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    party_size = form.cleaned_data.get('party_size')
    form_message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
    listing_address = listing.address
    message = "<html><body><p>" name + "</p><br><p>" + phone + "</p>
    <br><p>" + email + "</p><br><p>" + party_size + "</p><br><p>" + 
     listing_address + "</p><br></body></html>"
    msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_email,['email@gmail.com'])
    msg.content_subtype = "html"   # El contenido ahora sera text/html   
    send_mail('New Lead', message, 'to email', ['email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```